# How to erase certain element of a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Hello i'm curently coding a fonction that erase element from a vector of pointer(to class object), but i cant quite make it work.

I get this error
`error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<biblio::Reference*>::erase(biblio::Reference*&)’`

```
std::vector<Reference*> m_vReferences;          //Reference is a class
```

```
for ( auto iter : m_vReferences)                  //Loop for on every pointer to a class object
  {
    if (iter->reqId () == p_id)                   //Check if the id of the class object is the id we want
      {
        m_vReferences.erase (iter);               //Erase the pointer in the vector of pointer
      }
    else
      {
        throw EmptyReferenceException (iter->reqFormatedReference ());            //An exception
      }

  }
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase takes an iterator, you're giving it an element.

Comment: Vector does not support erasing by keys, cause there are no keys.

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) (from C++20 on).

Comment: `for ( auto iter : m_vReferences) ` is an example of bad naming. `iter` variable is not an iterator, it is an object of type `Biblio::Reference*`.

Comment: Calling `erase()` from within the loop is asking for trouble.  For example: when an element is erased, the `p_id`of the next element will NOT be checked...

Comment: worse... it's an UB. erase returns new iterator, iterator given to it becomes invalid and shouldn't be incremented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use auto-range loops when you want to delete the element from the container.
I would use std::remove_if as it is available in standard library.

```
m_vReferences.erase(std::remove_if(m_vReferences.begin(),m_vReferences.end(),[p_id](Reference* x){
   return x->reqId() == p_id;
}),m_vReferences.end());
```

or you may loop through vector find at which index is the element you want to delete and use erase function from vector.